# rhythmbox button icon names?

Tags: themes, icons, gtk, rhythmbox, icon-themes

The shuffle and loop/repeat button icons in rhythmbox don't match my gtk icon theme. I would assume that's because my theme is missing files named appropriately in order to theme those icons.

Is there anywhere I can go to find a comprehensive list of the required icon names to fully theme Rhythmbox? I don't know which ones I'm missing due to the fact that the amount of icons in a gtk icon theme is tremendous.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way:

Here's what i would do to find the list of icons it's using:
(Sure there must be a better way =)

Make sure rhythmbox isn't running (including in the background) then:

```
$ strace -f rhythmbox  2>&1 | grep '/usr/share/icons' | tee ~/foo
```

Close it.
Now we have the list of icons it uses with:

```
$ cat ~/foo | grep '\.\(png\|jpg\|svg\|xpm\)' | cut -d'"'  -f2 | sort -u
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/16/rhythmbox-set-star.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/symbolic/list-add-symbolic.svg
/usr/share/icons/Humanity/actions/symbolic/list-remove-symbolic.svg
...
```

In my case looks like shuffle is this one:

```
/usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/status/media-playlist-shuffle-symbolic.svg
```

Comment: Definitely not something I would have thought of! It would seem that gnome actually has a tool that displays all the common icons for your current gtk theme called `gtk3-icon-browser`. I ended up using that to find the icon names and fix the theme.